# What is the purpose of a function call a function itself as foobar.call(foobar)?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I had a question when reading a source code. The code example is as below:

```
// ... some code omitted
function p() {var u=new i();this. $Arbiter0=new s(); this.$Arbiter3=[];}
p.prototype.subscribe = function() { ... }

p.call(p) // <-- what is the purpose of this statement?
```

I'm new at JavaScript. I read from textbook that, when you use Function.call(Function), it usually means borrow inganother function constructor, in order to do some code-reuse/inherit stuff. BUT, I'm not sure what the purpose of doing it in this code example, i mean, **the function is calling the function itself**?

Clarify:

I know the use of Function.call(). I just want to know, what is the **benefit** of doing foobar.call(foobar)?

====

The complete source code is as below:

https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y6/r/USEL5meM70H.js

Search 'p.call(p)' in that source code. There is only one occurrence in that file.

====

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p.call(p)` has the effect of calling the function `p`, such that the value of `this`, within the function body, is the function itself.

This allows you to add properties to the function from within the function.

Relevant documentation for Function.call can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Since this is minified code, it's possible that this construct is an artifact of the minification process. It seems that the intent here is to initialize `p`; it's probably setting up data structures for storing subscribers.

Comment: sorry. i didn't ask it clearly. i want to ask what's the benefit of a function call a function itself? @Dancrumb

Comment: The function isn't calling itself. It's being called, with itself as the value of `this` in the body.
As to "why?", I haven't really seen this done before. I don't know that it's a particularly common pattern. It's valid JS, however.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument for the `.call` is the element that will be used as `this` in the executed function.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 0):

You know in JavaScript, functions are also Objects. That means you can have method and properties associated to functions.

For example :

I can create a function called **foo** and add a property to it like below

```
function Foo(){};
Foo.bar = [1,2,3,4,5];
Foo.sayName = function(){ alert("hi Tom")};
```

This methods are called as static methods ( Classical OOP pattern:  function constructor act like a class in javascript ), so that you don't need to instantiate an Object of **Foo** to access **sayName** method.

Coming back to the actual question. What happens when you do **Foo.call(Foo);**

The call method expect an object as the first parameter, and invoke the function on which it's called. When the function is invoked, **this** pointer will be pointed to the object passed. In this case, it's the Foo function ( Object ) itself.

Assume that if **Foo** function is written this way

```
function Foo(){
  this.bar = [1,2,3,4,5];
  this.sayName = function(){ alert("hi")};
}
```

After executing Foo.call(Foo), you can see that the actual **Foo** function ( Object ) will have the properties **bar** and method **sayName** got added.

I guess the script which you have sent is doing that to reduce code duplication.